# Google app engine python error TypeError: post() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Trying to implement a vote button with Ajax and jquery. I have the following handler for my upvotes

```
class Upvote(PageHandler):
    def post(self):
            logging.error("1")
```

And my upvote urls map to the handler like so:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', FrontPage),
                               ('/upvote_([0-9]+)', Upvote)
```

Now this is giving me the error

```
TypeError: post() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

However

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', FrontPage),
                               ('/upvote_2', Upvote)
```

works fine for upvote id 2. Can someone please tell me what I am missing here? Is the regex wrong? I'm a complete rookie so sorry if the question seems too naive.
Thanks.

EDIT: Changed ('/upvote_2)', Upvote) to ('/upvote_2', Upvote)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With no knowledge of the app you are using, I assume that the regex adds captured groups (enclosed by `(` `)`) as arguments. Removing the parentheses could solve your problem.